# override mkdir with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, unix, overriding, ld-preload, systrace

I'm trying to modify the syscall mkdir(), to filter some users who i don't want them to create directories, maybe this is not the most elegant way to do it, but i want to know why it's not working.

The mkdir() replacement code is:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define MAXGRUPOS 30
#define dim(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
#define true 1
#define false 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//
//Me permite llamar al metodo original
#include <dlfcn.h>
//codigos de error
#include <errno.h>

//mkdir()
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

//para obtener los usuarios
#include <unistd.h>

//parser de la config
#include <libconfig.h>
//#####################################################
#define RUTA_CONFIG "/etc/samba/gruposhabilitados.txt"
//#####################################################




int *obtenerGruposValidos(){

        int  indice = 1;

        int (*gruposValidos) = malloc(sizeof (int) * MAXGRUPOS);

        config_t cfg, *cf;
        const config_setting_t *grupos;
        int count = 0, n = 0, activo = 0;

        //add root 
        gruposValidos[0]=0;

        //init parser
        cf = &cfg;
        config_init(cf);


        if (!config_read_file(cf, RUTA_CONFIG )) {
           puts("ERROR al parsear\n");
           config_destroy(cf);
           return gruposValidos;
        }


        if(config_lookup_bool(cf, "Carpetas.activo", &activo)){
                if( activo == 0 ){
                           config_destroy(cf);

                           gruposValidos[1] = (int) getgid();
                           return gruposValidos;
                }//if
                else{

                        grupos = config_lookup(cf, "Carpetas.gruposHabilitados");

                        count = config_setting_length(grupos);

                        for (n = 0; n < count; n++) {
                                printf("Grupo: %d\n", (int) config_setting_get_int_elem(grupos, n));

                                gruposValidos[n+1] = ((int) config_setting_get_int_elem(grupos, n));
                        }  


                        config_destroy(cf);
                }//else
        }//if




        indice = n+1;
        while ( indice < MAXGRUPOS  )
                gruposValidos[indice++] = -1;

        return gruposValidos;


}//obtenerGruposValidos


int verificarGrupos(void){
  gid_t gids[MAXGRUPOS];
  int *gruposValidos = obtenerGruposValidos();
  int count, curr, aux;


  if ((count = getgroups(dim(gids), gids)) == -1){
    perror("getgroups() error");
    return false;
  }


  else {
    fflush(NULL);//me tiraba un error sin esto
    for (curr=0; curr<count; curr++){
        for(aux=0; aux < MAXGRUPOS; aux++){
              printf("%i-%i) Guid: %d - grupoValido: %d\n",curr,aux,((int) gids[curr]) ,(int) ((gruposValidos)[aux]));

              if  (((int) gids[curr]) == ((int) ((gruposValidos)[aux]) )){
                free(gruposValidos);
                return true;
                }//if
        }//for

    }//for

    free(gruposValidos);
    return false;
  }//else
}

int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode){
  int habilitadoAEscribir = false;

  puts("FALSE MKDIR");


  habilitadoAEscribir = verificarGrupos();

  if ( habilitadoAEscribir == true ){

        int (*mkdir_real)(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
        mkdir_real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"mkdir");

        mkdir_real(pathname, mode);
        return 0;

  }
   else{

        errno=EPERM;
        return(errno);
   }

}
int rmdir(const char *pathname){
  int habilitadoAEscribir = false;

  habilitadoAEscribir = verificarGrupos();

  if ( habilitadoAEscribir == true ){

        int (*rmdir_real)(const char *pathname);
        rmdir_real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"rmdir");
        rmdir_real(pathname);
        return 0;

  }
   else{
        errno=EPERM;
        return(errno);
       }
}
```

Compilling with  -Wall -std=c99 -fPIC -lconfig -ldl -shared

When i use with the mkdir binary, it works perfectly

> LD_PRELOAD=wrapper.so /bin/mkdir aDirectory

But when i use this way:

> LD_PRELOAD=wrapper.so bindfs A B
>   my mkdir() is not used.

I've tryed this implementation, it dosn't cover my needs, but works with binfs

```
#include <errno.h>
int mkdir() { errno = EPERM; return -1; }
int rmdir() { errno = EPERM; return -1; }
```

Comment: So if a user runs mkdir in a shell you want it to redirect to this call?

Comment: Or if a user uses the mkdir() call you want it to redirect here, too?

Comment: I want all uses of mkdir() in the bindfs mounted directory redirect to my mkdir() implementation

Comment: is root available for you? IE can you make a loadable kernel module? It may be easier.

Comment: Also, is the bindfs dir static? You could just hardcode `if(path contains /path/to/bindfs_dir/ do this, else do normal /usr/bin`

Comment: I've didn't thought this, sounds too complicated, maybe i will try to add a directory filter inside my mkdir(), and export the LD_PRELOAD to the whole system.

Comment: I've done the filter, it works, but i still have the same problem, even if i export LD_PRELOAD, all the other sessions continues with a blank LD_PRELOAD variable.

@Scotty Baue If i modify the code to make it kernel module, is possible that i cant get the same error?

Comment: If it's a kernel module and you override the `sys_mkdir()` you won't have to deal with the LD_PRELOAD stuff. Every call to mkdir, whether its from the shell or a c will go through the `sys_mkdir()`. In your kernel module, you can intercept the `sys_mkdir()` call determine the path, see what user is trying to mkdir and either let them do it or deny them access.

Comment: The problem is if you want this code to be portable you'll have to do some more stuff to overwrite the `sys_mkdir()` call which _can_ be portable but requires more code. If you don't want it to be portable you can hardcode the memory address to the syscall table into your code.